# Emulator and Phone restart in installation

Tags: android

I have an Android app with more 10.000 files in mp3, this files have a 2kb size.

When I put in the folder, only 6.000 files, the installation is successful, but with the 10.000 files, the installation stops and the emulator or Phone restarts and the app does not install.

**Update:**

The application is a dictionary with sound from words.

Comment: how big is the apk file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any limit on the number of files you're allowed to put in the various directories in your res folder. But it seems as though you've found such a limit. You are probably going to have to take a different approach if you want to use all of those files. Perhaps do not include them packaged in with the app and download them all the first time the app runs? Why would you need 10,000 different mp3 files out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a size limit on APKs, I believe its either 25 or 50MB. This has to do with the way apps are installed.